# Problema para cargar controladores de mi pagina web hecha con CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy aprendiendo a programar webs dinámicas con [php](/questions/tagged/php) usando el framework [codeigniter](/questions/tagged/codeigniter) y tengo una primera web dinámica hecha en mi PC (localhost) con algunas cosas (formulario de registro, log in y envío de mails desde formulario de contacto) que quiero probar desde un servidor web real.

Luego de pasar mucho trabajo arreglando las rutas de la página, modificando el `.htaccess` y el `config.php` para adaptar todo al server, la página funciona pero solo me permite entrar al controlador principal, el que viene por defecto, mandando el `error 404` de `codeigniter` si quiero entrar por otro controlador.

Tengo configuradas las URL cortas (para no tener que ingresar el molesto `index.php` para entrar a cada controlador, pero no funciona).

Ejemplo, si entro a:

```
www.nombredemiweb.com/index.php/controlador
```

me da `error 404`, igual que si entro a:

```
www.nombredemiweb.com/controlador
```

¿A qué se puede deber esto?

Desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Quizá necesites heredar los controladores desde core

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haz la prueba de poner el nombre del controlador que empiece en mayúscula en el hosting, o sea que si el controlador es

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
```

El fichero controlador tiene que ser

```
User.php
```

Puede ser que en tus pruebas en local el servidor que tengas no diferencie mayúsculas y minúsculas y el servidor de hosting sí.

Comment: No lo puedo creer, era eso! Muchas gracias! Me quemé las pestañas con los archivos de configuración sin encontrarle arreglo, y era esta simpleza de los nombres, ni lo había pensado. Gracias a todos por su colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes el script del controlador? Lo más probable es que no estás haciendo refecencia a una función... (en codeigniter las funciones dentro de los controladores son las urls del proyecto)

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Sitio extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function index()
    {
        echo "sitio - index";
    }

    public function general()
    {
        echo "sitio - general";
    }

}

?>
```

Para acceder sería: 
www.nombredemiweb.com/index.php/Sitio/index
www.nombredemiweb.com/index.php/Sitio/general

Answer (score 0):

Fijate que el nombre del controlador sea igual que

```
class Micontrolador extends CI_Controller {
```

osea el archivo tendria que ser

```
micontrolador.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Pregunta a tu pregunta
¿De casualidad usas  $config['base_url'] = ''?

Digo no se, quizas se te haya pasado por alto y le hayas escrito alguna ruta como su base_url.

Lo otro es respecto a la version de Codeigniter que tienes, la 3.04 tiene un update medio raro que por defecto utiliza la IP del servidor (o por lo menos eso hace en mi linux, de cualquier modo en mi server de Godaddy no ocurre.

lo otro que por aca te dejo el contenido del .htaccess que utilizo quizas te sirva de algo (deja en blanco el $config['index_page'])

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```